# Why is this clearInterval not reaching the var, though it is set as global?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goldrunt/SeAGU/80/)

After each circle object is created, it should increase in size while the mouse is down, and stop when mouse is up. clearInterval doesn't seem to reach the internal variable "growLoop" even though it's supposed to be global by declaring it first(which was the advice on many other posts about this same issue). In the console it shows growLoop undefined, but it's defined in line 95, right?
Also, the time interval seems to decrease with every new circle created, and they grow faster. How could the value of setInterval change?

```
 //set up canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var circles = [];

//create circle
function create(location) {
    circles.push({
        x: location.x,
        y: location.y,
        radius: 10,
        color: '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
    });
}

//figure out mouse position
var rect = document.getElementById("canvas").getBoundingClientRect();
// Get canvas offset on page
var offset = {
    x: rect.left,
    y: rect.top
};

function isOnCanvas(a) {
    if ((a.x >= 0 && a.x <= rect.width) && (a.y >= 0 && a.y <= rect.height)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function isOnCircle(a) {
    var i = 0,
        l = circles.length,
        x, y, d, c;
    for (; i < l; ++i) {
        c = circles[i];
        x = a.x - c.x;
        y = a.y - c.y;
        d = (a.radius || 10) + c.radius;
        if (x * x + y * y <= d * d) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// draw all circles
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        var p = circles[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

//make last drawn circle 1px bigger
function grow(){
    var a = circles[circles.length-1];
        a.radius += 1;
}

//find percentage of canvas filled in
var totalSpace = canvas.width * canvas.height;
var totalFilled = function () {
    total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        var p = circles[i];
        total += Math.PI * Math.pow(p.radius, 2);
    }
    return total;
    console.log(total);
}

    function findPercentage() {
        return (totalFilled() / totalSpace) * 100;
    }

    function updateInfo() {
        percentage = findPercentage();
        document.getElementById("percentage").innerHTML = "You've filled in " + percentage.toFixed(1) + "%";
    }

//do all the stuff
var animate = function(){
    draw();
    grow();
    updateInfo();}
var growLoop = 0;

window.onmousedown = function (e) {
    // get event location on page offset by canvas location
    var location = {
        x: e.pageX - offset.x,
        y: e.pageY - offset.y
    };

    if (isOnCanvas(location) && !isOnCircle(location)) {
        create(location);
        var growLoop = setInterval(animate, 100);
    }
};

window.onmouseup = function (e) {
    clearInterval(growLoop);
}
window.onmouseout = function (e) {
    clearInterval(growLoop);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var growLoop = setInterval(animate, 100);
```

By adding `var` here you are declaring an internal variable also named `growLoop` and not assigning to the global.  Remove `var`.

```
growLoop = setInterval(animate, 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeAGU/85/